# No logro coneccion con mi base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

He realizado ejercicios pequeños y he logrado agregar entradas desde un formulario y php, pero con éste proyecto no consigo ver el error por el que no se guardan las entradas.

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Formulario Completo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>3.2 Actividad. Trabajando con formularios y PHP</h1>
    <h2>Ian Cardoso Pillado</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>Formulario de Registro</h1>

    <form action="procesar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <!-- <label>Foto de perfil: </label>
      <input type="file" name="fotoPerfil"><br><br> -->
      <!-- End Sección para la actividad 3.3 Actividad integradora  -->

      <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
      <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"><br><br>

      <label for="direccion">Dirección:</label>
      <input type="text" id="direccion" name="direccion"><br><br>

      <label for="email">Correo Electrónico:</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br><br>

      <label for="confirm_email">Confirmar Correo Electrónico:</label>
      <input type="text" id="confirm_email" name="confirm_email"><br><br>

      <label for="telefono">Teléfono:</label>
      <input type="tel" id="telefono" name="telefono"><br><br>

      <label>Estado Civil:</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="casado" name="estado_civil" value="casado">
      <label for="casado">Casado</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="soltero" name="estado_civil" value="soltero">
      <label for="soltero">Soltero</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="viudo" name="estado_civil" value="viudo">
      <label for="viudo">Viudo</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="divorciado" name="estado_civil" value="divorciado">
      <label for="divorciado">Divorciado</label><br><br>

      <label>Aficiones:</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="leer" name="aficiones[]" value="leer">
      <label for="leer">Leer</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cine" name="aficiones[]" value="cine">
      <label for="cine">Ir al cine</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="viajar" name="aficiones[]" value="viajar">
      <label for="viajar">Viajar</label><br><br>

      <label for="estado">Estado:</label>
      <select id="estado" name="estado">
        <option value="" disabled selected>-----</option>
        <option value="Aguascalientes">Aguascalientes</option>
        <option value="Baja California">Baja California</option>
        <option value="CDMX">CDMX</option>
      </select><br><br>
      
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar"> 
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

El siguiente es mi codigo principal con el que proceso los datos del formulario y los mando tanto a la base de datos como a una segunda pagina de visualización
**procesar.php**

```
<?php
// Redirección a mostrar datos
session_start(); // Requerido para  gestionar redireccionamientos
header("Location: datos.php");

function infoError($cadena) {
    // Codificar la cadena para url
    $msg_url = urlencode($cadena);
    // Redirigir con parámetro GET
    if (!headers_sent()) {
        header("Location: error.php?msg=$msg_url");
        return;
    }
    // Redirección con JavaScript si se han enviado headers
    echo "<script> window.location.href='error.php?msg=$msg_url' </script>";
    exit; // Terminar la funcion
}

//Validar IMPUT TEXTs
if (!filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "nombre") || 
    !filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "email") || 
    !filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "telefono")) {
        infoError("Datos faltantes.");
} else {
    // Si todas las variables están presentes asignamos y comparamos el correo electrónico
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $confirm_email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "confirm_email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if (!$email) {
        infoError("Correo electrónico inválido.");
    } elseif ($email != $confirm_email) {        
        infoError("Los campos e-mail no coinciden entre sí.");
    }
}

// Sanitizando y asignando IMPUT TEXTs
$nombre = filter_var($_POST['nombre'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$direccion = filter_var($_POST['direccion'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];

// gestion de telefono, validacion y asignacion
if (!preg_match("/^\d{10}$/", $telefono)) {
    infoError("Numero de teléfono no válido");
} else {
    $telefono = filter_var($_POST['telefono'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}

// gestion de radio-buttons y asignacion estado civil
if (!isset($_POST['estado_civil'])) {
    infoError("Estado civil no seleccionado");
} else {
    $estado_civil = $_POST['estado_civil'];
}

// gestion de aficiones y asignacion de aficiones
if (!isset($_POST['aficiones'])) {
    $aficiones = "Ninguna seleccionada";
} else {
    $aficiones = $_POST['aficiones'];
    $cine = in_array('cine', $aficiones);
    $leer = in_array('leer', $aficiones);
    $viajar = in_array('viajar', $aficiones);
}

// gestion de estado y signacion de estado de la rep.
if (!isset($_POST['estado'])) {
    infoError("Estado de la republica no seleccionado");
} else {
    $estado = $_POST['estado'];
}

// Sección Base de Datos
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$clave = "";
$bd = "prueba";

$conn = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $clave, $bd);



$conn = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $clave, $bd);

// Verificar conexión
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    inforError("La conexión falló: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    infoLog("Conexión establecida correctamente.");
}

$insertar = "INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`nombre`, `direccion`, `email`, `telefono`, `estadoCivil`, `leer`, `cine`, `viajar`, `estado`, `id`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 

$stmt = $conn->prepare($insertar); 

if (!$stmt) {
    inforError("Error al preparar la consulta: " . $conn->error);
} else {
    infoLog("Consulta preparada correctamente.");
}

$stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $nombre, $direccion, $email, $telefono, $estado_civil, $leer, $cine, $viajar, $estado);

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    inforError("Error al insertar datos: " . $stmt->error);
} else {
    infoLog("Datos insertados correctamente.");
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

function infoLog($mensaje) {
    echo "[INFO] $mensaje\n";
}

function inforError($mensaje) {
    echo "[ERROR] $mensaje\n";
}



/* Fin sección Base de Datos */
// Almacenar variables en la sesión
$_SESSION['nombre'] = $nombre;
$_SESSION['direccion'] = $direccion;
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['telefono'] = $telefono;
$_SESSION['estado_civil'] = $estado_civil;
$_SESSION['aficiones'] = $aficiones;
$_SESSION['estado'] = $estado;
$_SESSION['imgName'] = $_FILES['fotoPerfil']['name'];
?>
```

En la siguiente pagina es donde muestro los datos del usuario
**mostrado de datos.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
// Recuperar variables de la sesión
$nombre = $_SESSION['nombre'];
$direccion = $_SESSION['direccion'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$telefono = $_SESSION['telefono'];
$estado_civil = $_SESSION['estado_civil'];
$aficiones = $_SESSION['aficiones'];
$estado = $_SESSION['estado'];

    $cine = in_array('cine', $aficiones);
    $leer = in_array('leer', $aficiones);
    $viajar = in_array('viajar', $aficiones);

// Sección Base de Datos
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$clave = "";
$bd = "prueba";

?>

<!-- Requerimento para manejar las seciones con redireccionamientos -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Mostrar datos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script>
        function redirigirIndex() {
            window.location.href = 'index.html';
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="header"><h1>3.2 Actividad. Trabajando con formularios y PHP</h1><h2>Ian Cardoso Pillado</h2></div>
    <div id="main">
    
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>Dato</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td><?php echo $nombre;?></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- <tr>
                <td>Datos de foto</td>
                <td><?php 
                echo "size: ".$fotoPerfil['size'] . "bites";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "tipo: ".$fotoPerfil['type'];
                echo "<br>";
                echo "ruta: ".$fotoPerfil['tmp_name'];
                echo "<br>";
                echo "name: ".$fotoPerfil['name'];
                ?></td>
            </tr> -->
            <tr>
                <td>Dirección</td>
                <td><?php echo $direccion; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Teléfono</td>
                <td><?php echo $telefono; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Estado Civil</td>
                <td><?php echo $estado_civil; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Aficiones</td>
                <td><?php print_r($aficiones); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Estado</td>
                <td><?php echo $estado; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <form name="back" id="back" action="procesar.php" method="post">

<p> <!-- Boton send -->
<button id="button" type="button" onclick="redirigirIndex();">Regresar</button>
</p> <!-- End Boton send -->

</form> 
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Descripción de mi base de datos**

```
localhost/prueba/       
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/sql&pos=0&db=prueba&table=usuarios
```

DESCRIBE usuarios;

nombre  varchar(255)    NO      NULL
direccion   varchar(255)    NO      NULL
email   varchar(255)    NO      NULL
telefono    varchar(255)    NO      NULL
estadoCivil enum('soltero','casado','divorciado','viudo')   NO      NULL
leer    tinyint(1)  NO      NULL
cine    tinyint(1)  NO      NULL
viajar  tinyint(1)  NO      NULL
estado  varchar(255)    NO      NULL
id  int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment

Comment: Hola. ¿Ves algún error en pantalla o en el log de errores? Por cierto, estás conectando **dos veces**.

Comment: mi mysql log está lleno de 
2024-03-19 14:41:53 576 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.column_stats: expected column 'min_value' at position 3 to have type varbinary(255), found type varchar(255).
2024-03-19 14:41:53 576 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.column_stats: expected column 'max_value' at position 4 to have type varbinary(255), found type varchar(255).

Comment: en la pantalla no veo nada raro, después de subir el formulario, me redirige a la pagina donde visualizo los datos pero la tabla de la base de datos no recibe entradas

Comment: En vez de `NO NULL`, debería ser `NOT NULL`. Por cierto, ¿usas xampp para windows, para mac o para linux? Eso podría ayudar a aclarar tu problema (al menos a mí)